# I am unable to test a custom Action in Kaizala app

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

I was able test custom Actions developed by my team. But after the latest update, I am unable to find these custom Actions in Discover.

Answer (score 0):

After recent update in Kaizala, testing of an Action has been restricted to flat groups (with less than 6 members) and group must have managed Action Palette for the user.

You can read more about the Testing of custom Action [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/kaizala-docs-preview/blob/master/kaizala/platform/v1/docs/actions/test.md). Currently, development of custom Actions is in preview mode. Hence to access this page, you must already be added to the GitHub project.